# SUMIFS with specific date range using EOMONTH

Tags: date, excel-formula

I will show some screenshots below to simply show the idea behind what I'm trying to achieve:

**1**

[image]

**2**

[image]

There was some custom formatting of the data types which I had to make in order to get dates on the monthly summaries on the right side of the worksheet to display as the text month, but I'm not sure if that is an issue now or not.

The SUMIFS formula I was using is:

```
=SUMIFS(B6:B200,A6:A200,">="&F7,A6:A200,"<="&EOMONTH(F7,0))
```

Comment: Please [edit] question to include formulas in text format not pictures.

Comment: Most likely F7 is just a text (= name of month) and not a date anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, If you are not sure about dates, then better to use Date in the format of `dd mmm yyyy`

Secondly, when you are testing on dates using operator `>=` and/ or `<=`, you need to ensure that the values will fall within this range. Therefore, I would use the formula like this `=SUMIFS(B6:B200, A6:A200, ">="&F7, A6:A200, "<="&EOMONTH(F7,0)+1)` wherein I am adding a Day extra to the value in cell `F7` to include data values of the last day of the month. To ascertain what I am saying correct, please test my manually summing up the values for a month or by using `SUM()`

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate you taking the time to assist!